# Loop over dictionary but also update it in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, iteration

```
def keysorting(self):
        eing = dict()  #my dic1
        tarnod = dict() #mydic2
        if self.has_cycle():
            raise Exception('There is a cycle!')
        else:
            for node in self.nodes():
                eing[node] = self.indeg(node)
            for node in self.nodes():
                tarnod[node] = self.target_nodes(node)

        for key, value in eing.items():
                if value == 0:
                    lst.append(key)
                    del eing[key]
                self.update(key, tarnod, eing)




   def update(self, key, tarnod, eing):
        if key in tarnod.keys():
            for val in tarnod[key]:
                eing[val] -= 1
            del eing[key]
            return eing
```

My biggest problem is that I want to loop over a dictionary that I am changing, so my code produced most of the times an error message telling me that the size of my dictionary has changed during iteration. I hope you guys can help me

**OK you guys, here is my question even more specific since you request it so hard:
how does my code has to be structured so that I loop over my dic1, then update it and then loop over the updated dic1 and do the same operations on this updated dic**

And don't forget: There are no bad questions, only bad answers ;-)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Step 2 should not be done inside the loop over the dictionary. You should break out of the loop once you find the value 0.

Comment: Post the code you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.
If you have failing code, see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your post; we'll work from there.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to implement this code correctly. The algorthm I worked out as I explained in my post comes from me, this is a fraction of a bigger task this is just one single method.  I though it is easier for everyone if I take out my code out of my context/class and post it as a general coding question.

Comment: Also, I stated what my biggest problem of the code was. It's not like I don't know anyhow to implement it, I fail at specific parts of the implementation (looping through my dic after updating it). Please also read my heading.

Answer (score 0):

> My biggest problem is that I want to loop over a dictionary that I am changing, so my code produced most of the times an error message telling me that the size of my dictionary has changed during iteration.

The solution to that in general is to loop over a copy of the thing you're changing, e.g:

```py
for key, value in list(eing.items()):
```

`list(eing.items())` will produce a list that lives its own life and will not be affected by

```py
del eing[key]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it matters that i loop over the changed dic because the order of elements in my_list matters, so it is important that the 2 comes before the 4 for example. And I know what order it needs because the 0 is an indicator that i need that element now. As I said, this  algortihm is part of a big class and this is just my method to order my elements. So if there is a 0 it means it comes next to be appended and that affects what element I choose next.

Comment: In what way does this mess up the order? In particular why did you feel the order was better with just `for key, value in eing.items():`?

Comment: No you are right, I understand it now after I tried it in my code. Thanks, I was able to work out my code for this. That was the answer I was looking for